# datatables with php and mssql using mssql_connect

Tags: php, sql, datatable

I would like to use jquery datatables to get data from a MS-SQL server with php. All examples I've found is to use *SQLSRV* driver, which only available on windows platforms, for the connection.

Can anyone give me some example or advices on how to use datatables with php and mssql by using `MSSQL_connect` as connect method?

**My enviroment is,**

Centos 6.5,
php 5.4,
MS SQL server 2003

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I need the same solution. I'm trying the code I found. You can try too. We just need to make the necessary changes.

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1910/datatables-with-php-and-mssql/p1

Comment: Please share an actual solution instead of link only.

Comment: @User2907101, I tried the link, but can't really modify the code to the way i want it, as datatables doesn't seems to be flexible when you have many joint tables.